# Displaying List of Files in a Folder with links

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to display a list of PDFs from a local network folder (not on the web but the folder is using a virtual directory to display the items on the web). The folder will have a new PDF added to it from time to time and in doing so, would like them displayed on the web page with the date that it was added as a list.

I attempted this:

```
private void ListImages()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("path here"));
    FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
    {
        if (file2.Extension == ".pdf")
        {
            list.Add(file2);
        }
    }

    DataList1.DataSource = list;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    candidatestatementsofinterest.Visible = true;
}
```

I get an error because it's trying to look on the server main folder instead of the network folder I used. I'm thinking I can't use MapPath?

Comment: You have obscured the two most important pieces of information.  What is the value of `path here`, and what is the error you get?

Comment: Sorry...

The path is "\\\\redfs\\dfsroot\\Susan\\WebDocs\\"

The error I get is "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\redfs\dfsroot\Susan\WebDocs'.

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant information rather than adding it in the comments, so that everyone will see it.

Comment: *"I'm thinking I can't use MapPath"* Probably true. Did you try it without using it? Something like: `new DirectoryInfo(@"\\redfs\dfsroot\Susan\WebDocs\")`

Comment: Also, `ArrayList` has been deprecated in favor of `List<T>`.

Comment: And the code could be shortened to: `DataList1.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\redfs\dfsroot\Susan\WebDocs\").GetFiles("*.pdf");`

Answer (score 0):

[`Server.MapPath(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8) consumes a relative URL and outputs the location on disk of that URL.

Since you don't have a URL, but rather an honest-to-goodness filesystem path, there's no need to ask Server.MapPath where you need to be.